# "Relay access denied" in django app using namecheap private email

Tags: python, django, email

So I have a Django app that sends confirmation emails to users who want to register their account. It looks something like this

`views.py`

```
def send_activation_email(user, request):
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    email_subject = "Activation Email"
    context = {"user": user, 
                "domain": current_site,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)), 
                'token': generate_token.make_token(user)
                }
    email_body = render_to_string('email/activate.html',context)

    email = EmailMessage(subject=email_subject, body=email_body, from_email=settings.EMAIL_FROM_USER, to=[user.email])

    email.send()
```

and with `settings.py` looking like this

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.privateemail.com'
EMAIL_FROM_USER = 'verification@ianisdo.xyz'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '[redacted]'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

The problem is that, when I try to send a email when the user creates an account, I get this error

```
SMTPRecipientsRefused at /register/

{'ianis.donica@gmail.com': (554, b'5.7.1 <ianis.donica@gmail.com>: Relay access denied')}
```

What I know for sure is:

- that it's not a problem with the private namecheap email, from which
  I can still send emails just not from my website.
- I also know the problem is not due to gmail not liking my email, as
  the same error when the email is sent to a yahoo.com domain.
- I also know that the issue is not with the `settings.py` not connecting
  to the `views.py`
- I also know that all the details are entered correctly

From my knowledge and talking to namecheap support, the issue is most likely caused by the header of the email but to my knowledge I can't seem to find anything wrong with it.

If someone is able to help me out, I would really appreciate it. I have had issues sending emails for about 9 days now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add a value for `EMAIL_HOST_USER` in your `settings.py`.  Without it, Django won't attempt to authenticate.  Here's the relevant bit from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-EMAIL_HOST_USER):

> `EMAIL_HOST_USER`
> Default: '' (Empty string)
>
> Username to use for the SMTP server defined in `EMAIL_HOST`. **If empty, Django won’t attempt authentication.**

The username should match the password setting you're already providing (i.e., a valid namecheap private email account).